# Finding vectors in two dimensional complex space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space ($n\geq 2$) over $\mathbb{C}$ with a non-degenerate scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)$. How can I find linearly independent vectors $u,v\in U$ such that $(u,u)=0,(v,v)=0$, but $(u,v)=1$?

Comment: It's impossible: $(u, u) = 0$ and $(v, v) = 0$ imply $u = v = 0$ (by the positiveness requirement in the definition of inner product). Then $(u, v) = (0, 0) = 0$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I dont think this is true. If $u=(1,i)$, then $(u,u)=0$.

Comment: In complex space, the standard inner product is $(u, v) = u^T\bar{v}$. "$u^Tv$" is not an inner product in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Of course you may interpret "scalar product" in a different way than me... so $(u, v) = u^Tv$ is OK, but it's better to explicitly define it.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks, I see the issue now. I rephrased my question to accomodate any non-degenerate inner product. In this way, I think my example might be valid now and am wondering how to find/construct such vectors?